# Terraform fails in CI while working fine locally when creating S3 bucket and flow logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have written the following Terraform code:

```
data "template_file" "external-bucket-policy" {
    template = "${file("${path.module}/policies/bucket-policy.tpl")}"

    vars {
        bucket-name = "${local.bucket_name}"
    }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "vpc_logs_recordsyes" {
    bucket = "${local.bucket_name}"
    acl = "private"
    force_destroy = false
    versioning {
        enabled = true
    }


    policy = "${data.template_file.external-bucket-policy.rendered}"

}
```

then I want to create VPC flow logs:

```
resource "aws_flow_log" "example" {
    log_destination      = "arn:aws:s3:::${local.bucket_name}"
    log_destination_type = "${var.log_destination_type}"
    traffic_type         = "${var.traffic_type}"
    vpc_id               = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
```

when running in CI I am getting the following:

```
aws_s3_bucket.vpc_logs_recordsyes: Creating...
  acceleration_status:         "" => "<computed>"
  acl:                         "" => "private"
  arn:                         "" => "<computed>"
  bucket:                      "" => "xsight-logging-bucket-Dev-us-east-1"
  bucket_domain_name:          "" => "<computed>"
  bucket_regional_domain_name: "" => "<computed>"
  force_destroy:               "" => "false"
  hosted_zone_id:              "" => "<computed>"
  policy:                      "" => "{\r\n    \"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\r\n    \"Statement\": [\r\n        {\r\n            \"Sid\": \"\",\r\n            \"Effect\": \"Deny\",\r\n            \"Principal\": {\r\n                \"AWS\": \"*\"\r\n            },\r\n            \"Action\": \"s3:DeleteBucket\",\r\n            \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::xsight-logging-bucket-Dev-us-east-1\"\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n             \"Sid\": \"DenyIncorrectEncryptionHeader\",\r\n             \"Effect\": \"Deny\",\r\n             \"Principal\": \"*\",\r\n             \"Action\": \"s3:PutObject\",\r\n             \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::xsight-logging-bucket-Dev-us-east-1/*\",\r\n             \"Condition\": {\r\n                     \"StringNotEquals\": {\r\n                            \"s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption\": \"AES256\"\r\n                      }\r\n             }\r\n        },\r\n        {\r\n            \"Sid\": \"DenyUnEncryptedObjectUploads\",\r\n            \"Effect\": \"Deny\",\r\n            \"Principal\": \"*\",\r\n            \"Action\": \"s3:PutObject\",\r\n            \"Resource\": \"arn:aws:s3:::xsight-logging-bucket-Dev-us-east-1/*\",\r\n            \"Condition\": {\r\n                \"Null\": {\r\n                    \"s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption\": true\r\n                }\r\n            }\r\n        }\r\n    ]\r\n}"
  region:                      "" => "<computed>"
  request_payer:               "" => "<computed>"
  versioning.#:                "" => "1"
  versioning.0.enabled:        "" => "true"
  versioning.0.mfa_delete:     "" => "false"
  website_domain:              "" => "<computed>"
  website_endpoint:            "" => "<computed>"
aws_flow_log.example: Creating...
  log_destination:      "" => "arn:aws:s3:::xsight-logging-bucket-Dev-us-east-1"
  log_destination_type: "" => "s3"
  log_group_name:       "" => "<computed>"
  traffic_type:         "" => "ALL"
  vpc_id:               "" => "vpc-3e2ab845"

Error: Error applying plan:

2 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket.vpc_logs_recordsyes: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_s3_bucket.vpc_logs_recordsyes: Error creating S3 bucket: InvalidBucketName: The specified bucket is not valid.
    status code: 400, request id: A2E94D42FF9CF218, host id: eD0zSCQ8+85kIIsctFeXcG4jLd4LDpeW0PRK01aq5JrWiW3qkyDKF76WeVKGgJVOcJT3gB2BBzk=
* aws_flow_log.example: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_flow_log.example: unexpected EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting an error from the AWS call which means something not correct at AWS side (and no issue with Terraform code).
Ref: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/blob/master/aws/resource_aws_s3_bucket.go#L583

Now, looking at the error, the important keyword is `Error creating S3 bucket: InvalidBucketName`.
This suggests bucket name you have chosen does not comply all the Naming convention.
Referring to AWS documentation(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html) suggests, a bucket name should **NOT** have **Upper Case**.

Can you update your Bucket name to `xsight-logging-bucket-dev-us-east-1` and try?

Also, for `vpc_flow` logging, you don't need to append `arn:aws:s3:::`.
You can just define as `log_destination = "${local.bucket_name}"`.
Ref: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/flow_log.html

Comment: "bucket name should NOT have Upper Case." I will remember that. Tks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your bucket name isn't a valid S3 bucket name as mentioned in the [AWS User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html#bucketnamingrules):

> The following are the rules for naming S3 buckets in all AWS Regions:
>
> - Bucket names must be unique across all existing bucket names in    Amazon S3.
> - Bucket names must comply with DNS naming conventions.
> - Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long.
> - **Bucket names must not contain uppercase characters or underscores.**
> - Bucket names must start with a lowercase letter or number.
> - Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels    are separated by a single period (.). Bucket names can
>     contain    lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must
>     start and    end with a lowercase letter or a number.
> - Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (for example,
>     192.168.5.4).
> - When you use virtual hosted–style buckets with Secure Sockets Layer    (SSL), the SSL wildcard certificate only matches buckets that don't
>     contain periods. To work around this, use HTTP or write your own
>     certificate verification logic. We recommend that you do not use
>     periods (".") in bucket names when using virtual hosted–style
>     buckets.

Specifically note the part that I have bolded that mentions that a bucket name must not contain uppercase characters while your plan shows that you are using an uppercase character in the S3 bucket name:

```
  bucket:                      "" => "xsight-logging-bucket-Dev-us-east-1"
```

Terraform can normally catch these types of errors at plan time as the validation is known ahead of time. Unfortunately it must also be backwards compatible and before 1 March 2018 buckets in US-East-1 had a less restrictive naming scheme for buckets so it's not easy to validate this at plan time.

---

On top of this, your flow logs have a race condition because Terraform is trying to create the S3 bucket and the VPC flow log at the same time.

To give Terraform a hint as to the dependency order of resources you can interpolate the output of one into the parameters of another or use `depends_on` where this isn't possible.

In your case you should just refer to the S3 bucket resource in the VPC flow log resource:

```
resource "aws_flow_log" "example" {
  log_destination      = "${aws_s3_bucket.vpc_logs.bucket}"
  log_destination_type = "${var.log_destination_type}"
  traffic_type         = "${var.traffic_type}"
  vpc_id               = "${var.vpc_id}"
}
```